# How can I avoid jitter when working with a 2D movement system?

Tags: unity, physics, camera, rigidbody

How can I avoid jitter in Unity?

Let's suppose that I want to create a 2D movement system using a Rigidbody 2D(Dynamic), and I want make the camera follow the character (which is a pixel art sprite).

How can I create a "jitter proof" 2D movement system for 2D pixel art games in Unity?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the jitter effect you're seeing, and the code/scene setup required to reproduce it? There are a number of potential errors that could create an effect described as "jitter," so showing a clear example can help focus answers on solving the problem you have, rather than unrelated problems with similar symptoms.

Comment: As @DMGregory suggest we need more information, how your camera follows the player?, Also the `LERP` might be a solution to your jitter